# failed to start rstudio (installed in Anaconda)

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio

In **Anaconda**, I installed **r essentials** & **r studio** , but failed to start rstudio. when I tried to launch, it first showed a white blank view:
[image]
and then it turned into a window explorer:
[image]
Though titled with **Download File**, but there's nothing.

checking log file (see below):

```
15 May 2018 02:23:25 [rdesktop] ERROR system error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified); OCCURRED AT: void __cdecl rstudio::core::http::NamedPipeAsyncClient::connectAndWriteRequest(void) C:\Users\builder\m64\conda-bld\rstudio_1519582538781\work\src\cpp\core\include\core/http/NamedPipeAsyncClient.hpp:84; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::desktop::NetworkReply::onError(const class rstudio::core::Error &) C:\Users\builder\m64\conda-bld\rstudio_1519582538781\work\src\cpp\desktop\DesktopNetworkReply.cpp:288
```

I wonder if anyone could help me to figure out the reason. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on my machine this week, using RStudio and R downloaded via Anaconda. I resolved this issue by uninstalling R and RStudio completely from Anaconda using the command on the Anaconda prompt: `conda uninstall r-base` and then installing R and RStudio from their respective official websites.

Unfortunately I couldn't figure out the source of the problem, but RStudio now works fine on my machine.

Comment: I did the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the installation of the latest Microsoft Windows 10 Home update, Version    10.0.17134 Build 17134.
You might revert this installation. But you will get reminders to install again.

Comment: I could solve it somehow by reinstalling Rstudio from https://dailies.rstudio.com/ See:https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2802