# How Can I Uninstall RStudio from Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, rstudio, uninstallation

I need to uninstall RStudio from Anaconda from my windows 10 laptop and cannot get it to work. Here is why and what I’ve tried so far.

Trying to launch RStudio Desktop (64 bit) from Anaconda I get a blank screen followed by a dialogue box asking that name a download file. This same issue documented in these three links.

1. [failed to start rstudio (installed in Anaconda)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50385198/failed-to-start-rstudio-installed-in-anaconda)
2. https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2802
3. https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-does-not-launch-properly/8630

The culprit is incompatibility with the latest version of Windows 10 and the fix is not scheduled any time soon.

All posts indicate RStudio (not actually R itself although some recommend do both) needs to be un-installed and then re-installed from their respective official sites.

I tried going through Windows control panel to uninstall it, but RStudio program does not show up in the list of available apps to uninstall. (I do see R for Windows 3.4 but that’s R itself not RStudio) I searched through file explorer and see the program in my AppData/local folder with a short cut to it in my start menu. Then there are dozens of references to RStudio from within Anaconda folders.

I've searched this site and many others including Git, RStudio Community, Anaconda documentation...everything explains uninstalling R-base or how generally to uninstall packages, but nothing about RStudio.

I also tried working through these alternative suggestions from RStudio support to no avail.

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488508-RStudio-Desktop-Will-Not-Start

What else can I try?

Answer (score 4):

To uninstall R studio from Anaconda, you can go into the Anaconda environment itself. In the environment there is a setting icon ( black wheel ) on each application icon. Click on that and then remove the application.

[image]